# Executar script em servidor remoto quando houver nova entrada no MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Por motivos de segurança, tenho 2 servidores. Em um está hospedado o site com toda a interface do usuário e a DB MySQL, e em outro está hospedada a aplicação que irá rodar o script a partir da solicitação do usuário. Eu preciso que, quando o usuário fizer uma solicitação através do site, essa solicitação vá para o banco de dados no Servidor 1 e este envie as informações para o Servidor 2 que irá executar um script dentro da aplicação com as informações enviadas pelo Servidor 1. Aqui eu desenhei a estrutura para ficar melhor a compreensão: [image: Estrutura]

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso? Toda nova entrada no MySQL no Servidor 1, o Servidor 2 execute um script?

Edit1: 
Ricardo, obrigado pela sugestão. Tentei de duas formas:

- inserir as informações no S1 e replicá-la para o S2 por log binário.
- executar um trigger no S1 que enviasse as informações para o S2 através de FEDERATED.

Em ambas as situações iria, através dessa inserção no S2, executar um trigger que iria chamar o script por UDF.

Infelizmente eu não pude colocar em prática pois não tenho acesso ao arquivo my.ini do S1, me impossibilitando de ativar o log binário ou o plugin FEDERATED.

Uma possível solução é enviar os dados simultaneamente para os dois servidores e ,apenas no S2, criar um trigger que irá executar o script através de UDF.

Comment: esse "toda nova entrada" pode ser detectado usando um `trigger`, e dentro do `trigger` pode executar um script

Comment: Ricardo, obrigado pela resposta! Mas existe uma forma de um trigger chamar a execução de um php em um servidor remoto? O trigger não seria apenas para execução de scripts no próprio servidor?

Comment: vc precisa executar a trigger no servidor remoto. Uma solução seria, uma trigger servidor 1 que grava numa tabela do servidor 2, e esse tem uma trigger nessa tabela para executar um script